# Can i view data on my Virtual machine from Azure portal?

Tags: azure

I have a VM in Azure. Is there a way I can navigate the c: drive of the machine from within Azure portal and not rdp?

Comment: I don't think you can navigate to the c: drive of the machine just in Portal. Maybe you do not actually what you want. Please provide more details about what issue you meet and messages about the issue.

Comment: Looks like your workspace got deleted and you are trying to recover files. Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use Azure Bastion service: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-create-host-portal

Or Run Command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. If you are looking for a shortcut, instead of connecting to RDP, it is not possible.

You can use Azure File storage instead if you need similar functionality.

Comment: I cant seem to connect rdp anymore .. settings have been changed , although they tell me should have access. But I have just come across an error :            The workspace (xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx) associated with this virtual machine could not be found. This usually happens if you do not have access to this workspace or the workspace is deleted. 
Please verify the existence of the workspace .  Can I get the name of the workspace that may have been deleted or that I am not a member of from the Guid ?